# How do I loop through a JSON array object in an AJAX response using each?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have a JSON object returned via ajax. When I try to access an array of strings in the response, I get undefined. I can see from the console log that the array exists and is populated.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url,
  dataType: 'JSON'
}).done(function( response ) {
  $.each(response, function(){
    myConcatenatedTags = ''
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.tags);
    for (var tag in this.tags) {
      myConcatenatedTags += tag;
    }
  });
});
console.log(myConcatenatedTags);
```

Response object

```
Object
    _id: "598be40d9c7685725199cea3"
    comments: "sometext"
    number: "sometext"
    quote: "sometext"
    source: "sometext"
    tags[]: Array[3]
        0: "tag1"
        1: "tag2"
        2: "tag3"
        length: 3
```

Yet `console.log(this.tags);` results in `undefined`, and `console.log(myConcatenatedTags);` prints an empty array.

If I try to access an index:

```
console.log(this.tags[0]);
// response
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

What gives?

---

Update

The problem was how I was referencing the element.

Elements get referenced like so: `this.source`

But lists get referenced as a key, rather than with a dot notation: `this["tags[]"]`

And a `console.log` of `this["tags[]"]` looks as expected:

```
console.log(this["tags[]"]);
// ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
```

Additionally, the mark for duplicate is inaccurate, as the access was in the `.done` callback. How do I get this removed?

Comment: what does `typeof response` shows you ?

Comment: `console.log(typeof(response));` gives me `object`

Comment: Hum the duplicates doesn't look really related to OP's question: everything he gets is in the callback of done function

Comment: I considered that this was due to the asynchronous nature, but I'm confused why I'm able to log non-array elements of the response. For example, `console.log(this.source);` shows exactly what I would expect: `sometext`. So why am I unable to access the array?

Comment: well I'm not sure what your this refer to. I had an answer related to your use of `$.each` which is wrong since you need an array, not an object. Instead you could use [`for...in`](//mdn.io/for...in), or loop over `Object.keys(response)` or if you are using lodash, `_.each` handle this pretty well

Comment: `this` refers to the current index of the response object in `$.each(response, function(){`

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `console.log(tags)` is called before the function `.done()` has been executed.

Comment: Then why is it I can log the non-array elements? For example, `console.log(this.source);` shows exactly what I would expect: `sometext`.

Comment: @modle13 Where is `source` defined?

Comment: It's an element of the response object. I'm pulling all of this from a Mongo doc.